# merge adjacent repeated rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to merge adjacent repeated rows into one ,
for example , I have a table demo with two columns ,

```
data | order
-------------
 A   | 1 
 A   | 2
 B   | 3
 B   | 4
 A   | 5
```

I want the result to be :

```
A
B
A
```

How to achieve this by one select SQL query in oracle ?

Comment: use the order by selected out results .

Comment: I updated my question . If I have a order column which can be used to generate order , then how to write the sql ? :D @Mat

Comment: Hint: Tabibitosan (http://rwijk.blogspot.nl/2014/01/tabibitosan.html)

Comment: [hmm see here not sure](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17751)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please, try something like this

```
select *
from table t1
where not exists(select * from table t2 where t2.order = t1.order - 1 and t1.data = t2.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer suggested by Dmitry above is working in SQL, to make it work in oracle you need to do some modifications.

`order` is a reserved keyword you need to escape it as follows.

```
select 
    *
from 
    Table1 t1
where not exists(
    select * from Table1 t2 
  where 
      t2."order" = t1."order" - 1 
    and 
      t1."data" = t2."data"
) order by "order"
```

Working Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc816/3

Comment: *‘The answer suggested by Dmitry above is working in SQL, to make it work in oracle …’* – actually, in Oracle you are working with data using SQL, so what you have written there doesn't make much sense. On the other hand, if by *SQL* you meant *SQL Server* (a database product by Microsoft), that is still incorrect, because in SQL Server's SQL, `order` is a reserved word too. I honestly believe that your good and valid point should just be either a comment or an edit to Dmitry's answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can group by a column

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html

Example from official oracle site:

```
SELECT AVG (flying_time), orig_airport
FROM Flights
GROUP BY orig_airport
```

Comment: Cannot use group by , because the result will be "A B" , not "A B A" . I just want to deleted repeated adjacent rows . :D